# What is the best way to add footer to all fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have one Android application(Xamarin.Android) and it has many fragments.
All fragments have the link to website in bottom.

Ideally I'd like to create it as custom fragment with link to website and add to all fragments.

But I don't find any way to add this fragment to XML of every fragment without coding.
I don't want to add the custom fragment to FrameLayout of other fragments in code.

Please let me know if anyone knows best solution for this kind of footer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add the footer to the activity and use fragments for other screens. (Fragment frame layout above the footer in the main activity obviously)

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@+id/footer">

   </FrameLayout>

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/footer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:text="Footer content"/>
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. You can make a custom layout with your footer view at the bottom of the view and extend it for all your parent layouts.

Comment: Solution 1 is interested. layout_height of FrameLayout that replaces fragment should be wrap_content?

Comment: if only some fragments need the footer?

Comment: You could make it match parent with a parent RelativeLayout. If you want the footer for some fragments only then you could  just hide the footer programmatically or just create a separate footer layout xml file and use include tag in those fragment layouts you need to display your footer.

Comment: Right. Exactly I want to add footer to some fragments. I want to work on only fragments' layout. I don't want to add any code for footer in fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way that I found.

- Create new XML layout for footer
- Create custom fragment class for this footer
- Add this footer fragment to end of layout as needed as following

That's all!